# Financial Account cannot be change to non deductible

Tags: financial-accounts

This seems like a core issue, possible with 4.7, but I cannot find under https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues

Once a Financial Account has been marked as deductible, it cannot be changed back to non-deductible.

To reproduce:
Edit a non deductible Financial Account
Check box for "deductible?"
Save
On the Financial Accounts screen, the account will now show as Deductible
Edit the same Financial Account (which is now deductible)
Uncheck box for "deductible?"
Save
On the Financial Accounts screen, the account will not have changed

Comment: Do you mean Financial Type?

Comment: no I mean Financial Account

Answer (score 3):

This is a core bug and have reported issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/28  and also submitted fix at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12500

Can you please try after applying the patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12500.patch)?

If the patch works without any error than please comment on the [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12500) as it would help for PR to get merge quickly into core.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: patch is merged for 5.5 release

Comment: Pradeep, thanks so much. the patch works great. I have commented with thank you on PR

Comment: So can you mark this as answer for your question?